# Ansible - wait_for empty file

Tags: ansible

I am looking for a way to use wait_for to test for an empty file, but I cannot seem to find a regex that works. "^$" should theoretically work but it does not seem to be the case.

Sample playbook (ansible 2.7.1) :

```
- name: Create file with data
  lineinfile:
    dest: /tmp/test_file
    line: 12345
    state: present
    create: yes

- name: Wait for /tmp/test_file to contain 12345 - this test should pass
  wait_for:
    path: /tmp/test_file
    search_regex: "12345"
    timeout: 2

- name: Wait for /tmp/test_file to be empty - this test should fail but it passes
  wait_for:
    path: /tmp/test_file
    search_regex: "^$"
    timeout: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet that correct regular expression is `\A\Z`:

```
- name: Wait for /tmp/test_file to be empty - this test should fail but it passes
  wait_for:
    path: /tmp/test_file
    search_regex: '\A\Z'
    timeout: 2
```

`$` and `^` are tricky with MULTILINE regexp.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax
`\A` Matches only at the start of the string.
`\Z` Matches only at the end of the string.